# $T(2N)/T(N)$ ~ $2^b$ (Please help me step out this simplification)

Tags: algorithms

Algorithms textbook says if $T(N)$ ~ $aN^blgN$ then $T(2N)/T(N)$ ~ $2^b$

$$T(2N)/T(N) = a(2N)^blg2N/aN^blgN$$
$$= 2^b(1+lg2/lgN)$$ $$ = 2^b$$

Comment: Notes: I don't understand how to get from step 1 to step 2. step 1 and step 2 to 3 I do get. Also step 3 is not an equality it's a '~' I couldn't figure out how to get that symbol into the formatting, will someone please edit appropriately and I look at what you did?

Comment: Further note: I am reading a text book but this is not a homework problem lol, I'm long past getting paid to study.

Comment: Note in my problem and the solution. In the problem I neglected to put $lg(2N)$ in parantheses but wrote instead $lg2N$ which means something different and messes the whole thing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

The Key is to represent $lg(2N)$ as $(lg2 + lgN)$

$$a(2N)^blg(2N)/aN^blgN = a2^bN^b(lg2 + lgN)/aN^blg^N$$ 
$$ = 2^b(lg2+lgN)/lgN$$
$$ = 2^b(lg2/lgN + lgN/lgN) $$
$$ = 2^b(lgN/lgN + lg2/lgN)$$
$$ = 2^b(1 + lg2/lgN)$$
$$ = 2^b$$

Comment: again the final $ = 2^b $ is wrong. the = sign should be a tilde but I can't figure out how to get that into the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{lg2}{lgN}=o(1)$$

Comment: Thank you but the final step I already get.